# Is there any substance that is liquid at room temperature and pressure that doesn't contain H as one it's constituents apart from mercury?

Tags: solubility, hydrogen

I want to know if there's any substance that is liquid at room temperature and atmospheric pressure that doesn't contain HYDROGEN atom(s) in its make up. Any substance dissolved in water or any substance that contains HYDROGEN is not required

Comment: Why did you ask this and immediately self-answer? What are you trying to accomplish? A complete list of substances? That is impossible to get as there are too many. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: I would suggest doing some research before asking a question. Simply searching up elements at room temperature would have given you an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are not going to get a list of compounds which fit your description. It's a very general question. However, many compounds of the form $\ce{C_nX_{2n+2}}$, where X is a halogen for example, are liquids at room tempterature, and contain no hydrogens.

Examples:

[Perfluorooctane:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfluorooctane)

[image]

Melting point: $-25^o C$, Boiling point $103^oC$

[Perfluoromethylcyclohexane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfluoromethylcyclohexane)

[image]

Melting point: $-37^o C$, Boiling point $76^oC$

[Perfluorodecalin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfluorodecalin)

[image]

Melting point: depends on the isomer, Boiling point $142^oC$

You can read about [fluorocarbons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorocarbon). Many of these are liquids.

Comment: Nice, and many chlorocarbons as well.

Comment: And, if I recall correctly, oxygen is soluble in perfluorodecalin.  Due to its chemical inertness, we can theoretically "breathe" an oxygenated solution of this liquid.

Comment: @ChemProfMatt **Very soluble** apparently. ["100 mL of perfluorodecalin at 25 °C can dissolve 49 mL of oxygen at STP"](http://www.f2chemicals.com/pdf/technical/Gas%20solubility.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Bromine. Melting point: - 7.2 degree Celsius, boiling point: + 58.8 degree Celsius 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromine

Answer (score 0):

Carbon disulphide and bromine are both liquids at room temperature and atmospheric pressure. They do not contain hydrogen atoms. Some elements become liquids at or near room temperature they include gallium, caesium and francium .I'm sure they're still other substances that are liquids at room temperature and atmospheric pressure.

Comment: Define room temperature.

Answer (score 0):

One could make the argument that gallium is a liquid at room temperature, if you're willing to fudge a few degrees and go up to 30 C.  Say "room temperature on an unseasonably warm day".